# Docker stop exiting with 0

Tags: docker, containers

I am getting crazy.... I cannot understand why my container stops just after run.

this is my Dockfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

ENV DEVICE name
ENV PASSWORD pass

COPY install.sh /
#debdir is a directory
COPY debdir /debdir
RUN chmod +x /install.sh

CMD ["/install.sh"]
EXPOSE 5000 5314
```

and the install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg -i /debdir/*.deb
/opt/MXB/sbin/configure-fp.sh --user=$DEVICE --password=$PASSWORD --encryption-method="AES-128" --encryption-key="SECUR_ITY2014a" --use-proxy=false
```

Can you help me?

when the service "mxb" finish starting the container will exit with 0 instead of keep runnig with option -i -t, I tried with -dit too.

I run with this:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -p 5000:5000 -p 5314:5314 -e "DEVICE=device" -e "PASSWORD=pass" --name iaso_mxb iaso_mxb
```

many thanks.

logs:

```
sudo docker logs af6bbff2a4f1
Selecting previously unselected package mxb.
(Reading database ... 7562 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /debdir/mxb_~linux-1_amd64.deb ...
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing ......
'./var/log/BRMigrationTool/BRMigrationTool_2017_05_30.log' -> '/tmp/BRMigrationTool_2017_05_30.log'
Unpacking mxb (17.4.1.17122-1) ...
Setting up mxb (17.4.1.17122-1) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Functional Process configuration tool, version 17.4.1.17122
Copyright (c) 2017 MXB

[ ok ] Starting ProcessController:.

Initialization in progress. It can take a while...
...
...
Functional process initialized successfully.
```

in this point the service should keep running.

Comment: Why would you expect it to do anything different?

Comment: Is there any output? `docker logs contianerid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your container lives as long as it has something to do in the

`CMD`

or

`ENTRYPOINT`

directive of the Dockerfile, then it exits.

By the way what do you expect it to do?

A Nginx container launches Nginx, a MongoDB launches a MongoDB database...

This is normal and you may, for example, add

`;sleep infinity`

at the end of your install.sh

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I try to create a container for the IASO back manager to run inside Unraid tower.

Comment: Post `docker logs your_container_or_id` as requested